# How is Lung in Lung Dragon correctly pronounced?

Tags: monsters, dnd-3e, pronunciation

OK, so I've fished out my copy of 3rd Edition *Oriental Adventures*, and on looking at the lung dragons' entry in the monster chapter, I'm unsure how to pronounce lung- is it the same as the breathing organ or is it pronounced *loong*?

Comment: The “lung” of “lung dragon” refers to the Chinese word for dragon, 龙 (often transliterated “long,” “lung,” or “loong”). You would probably get better answers from the [Chinese Language Stack Exchange](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/)—even if someone publishing D&D had tried to offer pronunciation guidance, the Chinese word is what they were going for, so experts in Chinese Language may very well have better guidance.

Answer (score 8):

### Similar to "long" in English

A Lung (or long) dragon is a [traditional Chinese dragon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_dragon), with the Chinese character 龙 (simplified) or 龍 (traditional).

The pronounciation differs somewhat depending on the dialect of Chinese you speak. Here is a whole [list of speakers pronouncing](https://forvo.com/word/%E9%BE%99/) it, in Mandarin, Cantonese, and other variants of Chinese.

Most of them sound like a slightly streched out English "long". The [IPA phonetic transcripiton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet) is `[lóŋ]`.

You also can hear the "default" pronounciation by either entering it into [Google Translate](https://www.google.com/search?q=translate), and clicking the loudspeaker symbol, or see [this short YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vnpjyMret90).

Comment: That's not the IPA phonetic transcription — what you've written would end in an [n] (alveolar nasal) followed by a [g] (voiced velar stop).

Comment: To clarify jogloran's comment a bit, the sound spelled in English as "ng" is considered by the IPA to be [a single consonant, transcribed as `ŋ`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_velar_nasal)

Comment: @IMSoP I think you are right. [This site](https://easypronunciation.com/en/chinese-pinyin-phonetic-transcription-converter) claims it is [lóng], but in all the pronounications it does not really have a voiced "g" stop, so ŋ seems to be the correct way to represent it in IPA. I updated it.